# VK_FILTER_NEAREST not working during sampling

Tags: c++, image, vulkan

I have a problem with my sampler in Vulkan: it doesn't matter if I create the sampler with `VK_FILTER_NEAREST` or `VK_FILTER_LINEAR` for both magnification or minification filter, my texture will be sampled as if I created it with `VK_FILTER_LINEAR`;

This is the method where I create my sampler:

```
void                         Gui::Texture_2D::createVkSampler(const VkFilter & _magFilter,
                                                              const VkFilter & _minFilter,
                                                              const VkSamplerMipmapMode & _mipMapFilter,
                                                              const unsigned char & _maxAnisotropy) {
    VkSamplerCreateInfo samplerInfo = {};

    samplerInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SAMPLER_CREATE_INFO;
    samplerInfo.magFilter = _magFilter; // VK_FILTER_NEAREST
    samplerInfo.minFilter = _minFilter; // VK_FILTER_NEAREST
    samplerInfo.addressModeU = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.addressModeV = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.addressModeW = VK_SAMPLER_ADDRESS_MODE_REPEAT;
    samplerInfo.anisotropyEnable = _maxAnisotropy == 0 ? VK_FALSE : VK_TRUE; // 0
    samplerInfo.maxAnisotropy = _maxAnisotropy; // 0
    samplerInfo.borderColor = VK_BORDER_COLOR_INT_OPAQUE_BLACK;
    samplerInfo.unnormalizedCoordinates = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareEnable = VK_FALSE;
    samplerInfo.compareOp = VK_COMPARE_OP_ALWAYS;
    samplerInfo.mipmapMode = _mipMapFilter; // VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_NEAREST
    samplerInfo.mipLodBias = 0.0f;
    samplerInfo.minLod = 0.0f;
    samplerInfo.maxLod = static_cast<float>(image.getMipLevels());

    if (vkCreateSampler(logicalDevice, &samplerInfo, nullptr, &sampler) != VK_SUCCESS)
        throw std::runtime_error("Texture sampler creation failed!");

}
```

...but the texture is rendered as if I passed `VK_FILTER_LINEAR` and `VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_LINEAR`, and I really don't know what's wrong.

Does someone have an idea? Thanks.

**More Info**:

This is the image texture (a simple 8x8 .png with every 4x4 corner of a different color):

[image: Here]

This is the result using `VK_FILTER_NEAREST` and `VK_SAMPLER_MIPMAP_MODE_NEAREST`:

[image: Here2]

This is the .obj file of the cube, with Normals and Texture Coordinates:

```
# Blender v2.79 (sub 0) OBJ File: ''
# www.blender.org
mtllib untitled.mtl
o Cube
v 1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 -1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
v 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 1.000000
v -1.000000 1.000000 -1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 1.000000 0.000000
vt 1.000000 1.000000
vt 0.000000 1.000000
vn 0.0000 -1.0000 0.0000
vn 0.0000 1.0000 0.0000
vn 1.0000 0.0000 0.0000
vn -0.0000 -0.0000 1.0000
vn -1.0000 -0.0000 -0.0000
vn 0.0000 0.0000 -1.0000
usemtl Material
s off
f 1/1/1 2/2/1 3/3/1 4/4/1
f 5/5/2 8/6/2 7/7/2 6/8/2
f 1/1/3 5/9/3 6/10/3 2/11/3
f 2/12/4 6/13/4 7/7/4 3/14/4
f 3/15/5 7/16/5 8/17/5 4/4/5
f 5/5/6 1/18/6 4/19/6 8/20/6
```

I would expect a Minecraft-like behaviour, but I get this blurry style that I should obtain with `VK_FILTER_LINEAR`.

Thanks.

**Update**

I ran the program on another pc and the texture is sampled correctly, I suppose there's a bug/glitch/problem with my GPU, I'll try to update my drivers.

**Update 2**

I updated my GPU drivers and I'm now using the latest Vulkan SDK version (1.1.101.0), still nothing; RenderDoc analysis of the sampler reports no problem, I'm using the right filter; Removing/Not using mipmaps doesn't help; Not a single Validation layer error.

I'm starting to think my GPU still doesn't support Vulkan very well (Intel HD Graphics 620) so I guess I'll have to accept it and go on, knowing that at least it'll work on other PCs.

**Update 3**

I updated my GPU drivers and I'm now using the latest Vulkan SDK version (1.1.114.0), still nothing; RenderDoc analysis of the sampler reports no problem, I'm using the right filter; Removing/Not using mipmaps doesn't help; Not a single Validation layer error.

I'm starting to think my GPU still doesn't support Vulkan very well (Intel HD Graphics 620) so I guess I'll have to accept it and go on, knowing that at least it'll work on other PCs.

Comment: I would imagine that the bug lies elsewhere - perhaps you end up not using that sampler somehow. If you haven't already, I'd recommend you enable validation layers. Assuming no validation layer errors, I recommend you run through RenderDoc - you can inspect the details of the entire pipeline state in there.

Comment: That sampler is the only one in my program, so I'm definitely using it, also, no validation layer errors.

Comment: Please provide a complete example in that case, it's impossible to debug fragments ... https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If that's really the sampler you pass to your shader then it should do nearest filtering. But without all of the relevant code parts, it's hard to judge. Easiest way would be running this through e.g. RenderDoc and check if the sampler values you've setup are actually passed to the api.

Comment: @SaschaWillems I took a screenshot with RenderDoc and inspected the Sampler during the vkCmdDrawIndexed: https://i.imgur.com/ve5SEsz.png as you can see, I'm using the correct sampler, also, `NEAREST` mode is enabled (Bottom-right).

Comment: Odd. I just plugged your texture into my own samples with nearest filtering and it works as expected. Does your texture have multiple mip levels? If so try not using any mip levels and check any driver setting that may affect texture filtering.

Comment: I updated both my driver video and the Vulkan SDK (Now using 1.1.97.0), but still nothing. Also, even without using mip levels, texture is not sampled correctly (The program runs fine on my other pc, texture sampled perfectly and everything).

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same issue and decided to mess around with `VkSamplerCreateInfo` and found out that setting `anisotropyEnabled` to `VK_FALSE` fixes the problem, but I don't know why.